# css transform animations not working in react jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to make a smooth open/close sidebar work in React.
I found this non-react example which I really like:

https://jsfiddle.net/nickleefly/dxuynqw7/

And I have been trying to convert it into a React component:

https://jsfiddle.net/martinradio/sedmh523/1/

```js
class TodoApp extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
       <div>

                <label htmlFor="sidebar-checkbox" className="sidebar-toggle"></label>
                <input type="checkbox" className="sidebar-checkbox" id="sidebar-checkbox"></input>


                <div className="sidebar" id="sidebar">

                    <div className="sidebar-item">
                        <p>Find the things you love but forgot to save.</p>
                    </div>

                    <nav className="sidebar-nav">
                        <a className="sidebar-nav-item" href="/">Home</a>
                        <a className="sidebar-nav-item" href="/get-started">Get Fetching</a>
                        <a className="sidebar-nav-item" href="http://app.fetching.io/sessions/new">Login</a>
                        <a className="sidebar-nav-item" href="/faq">FAQ</a>
                        <a className="sidebar-nav-item" href="/blog">Blog</a>
                        <a className="sidebar-nav-item" href="/about">About</a>
                        <a className="sidebar-nav-item" href="/privacy-policy">Privacy</a>
                        <a className="sidebar-nav-item" href="/privacy-policy" data-uv-trigger>Contact Us</a>
                    </nav>

                </div>

                <div className="wrap">
                    
                    <div className="topnav">
                        <a className="active" href="#home">Home</a>
                        <a href="#news">News</a>
                        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                        <a href="#about">About</a>
                    </div>
                    
                    page content page content page content page content 
                    <br></br>
                    page content page content page content page content 
                    <hr></hr>
                    page content page content page content page content 
                    <br></br>
                    page content page content page content page content 
                    <hr></hr>
                    page content page content page content page content 
                    <br></br>
                    page content page content page content page content 
                    <hr></hr>
                    
                
                </div>

            </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
/* http://fetching.io/
 *  ___
 * /\_ \
 * \//\ \      __      ___   __  __    ___     ___
 *   \ \ \   /'__`\  /' _ `\/\ \/\ \  / __`\ /' _ `\
 *    \_\ \_/\ \_\.\_/\ \/\ \ \ \_\ \/\ \_\ \/\ \/\ \
 *    /\____\ \__/.\_\ \_\ \_\/`____ \ \____/\ \_\ \_\
 *    \/____/\/__/\/_/\/_/\/_/`/___/> \/___/  \/_/\/_/
 *                               /\___/
 *                               \/__/
 *
 * Designed, built, and released under MIT license by @mdo. Learn more at
 * https://github.com/poole/lanyon
 */


/*
 * Contents
 *
 * Global resets
 * Masthead
 * Sidebar
 * Slide effect
 * Posts and pages
 * Pagination
 * Reverse layout
 * Themes
 */


/*
 * Global resets
 *
 * Update the foundational and global aspects of the page.
 */

/* Prevent scroll on narrow devices */
html,
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

html {
  font-family: "PT Serif", Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-family: "PT Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #313131;
  letter-spacing: -.025rem;
}


/*
 * Wrapper
 *
 * The wrapper is used to position site content when the sidebar is toggled. We
 * use an outter wrap to position the sidebar without interferring with the
 * regular page content.
 */

.wrap {
  position: relative;
}



/*
 * Sidebar
 *
 * The sidebar is the drawer, the item we are toggling with our handy hamburger
 * button in the corner of the page.
 *
 * This particular sidebar implementation was inspired by Chris Coyier's
 * "Offcanvas Menu with CSS Target" article, and the checkbox variation from the
 * comments by a reader. It modifies both implementations to continue using the
 * checkbox (no change in URL means no polluted browser history), but this uses
 * `position` for the menu to avoid some potential content reflow issues.
 *
 * Source: http://css-tricks.com/off-canvas-menu-with-css-target/#comment-207504
 */

/* Style and "hide" the sidebar */
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;

  visibility: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  font-family: "PT Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: .875rem; /* 15px */
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.6);
  background-color: #202020;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
          transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
@media (min-width: 30em) {
  .sidebar {
    font-size: .75rem; /* 14px */
  }
}

/* Sidebar content */
.sidebar a {
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #fff;
}
.sidebar-item {
  padding: 1rem;
}
.sidebar-item p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

/* Sidebar nav */
.sidebar-nav {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.1);
}
.sidebar-nav-item {
  display: block;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.1);
}
.sidebar-nav-item.active,
a.sidebar-nav-item:hover,
a.sidebar-nav-item:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
  border-color: transparent;
}

@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .sidebar-item {
    padding: 1.5rem;
  }
  .sidebar-nav-item {
    padding-left:  1.5rem;
    padding-right: 1.5rem;
  }
}

/* Hide the sidebar checkbox that we toggle with `.sidebar-toggle` */
.sidebar-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

/* Style the `label` that we use to target the `.sidebar-checkbox` */
.sidebar-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top:  1rem;
  display: block;
  padding: .5rem .65rem;
  color: #505050;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.sidebar-toggle:before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  padding-bottom: .125rem;
  border-top: .375rem double;
  border-bottom: .125rem solid;

  /* Make the border inside the box */
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

.sidebar-toggle:active,
#sidebar-checkbox:checked ~ .sidebar-toggle {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #505050;
}

@media (min-width: 30.1em) {
  .sidebar-toggle {
    position: fixed;
    width: 2.25rem;
  }
  .sidebar-toggle:before {
    padding-bottom: .15rem;
    border-top-width: .45rem;
    border-bottom-width: .15rem;
  }
}


/* Slide effect
 *
 * Handle the sliding effects of the sidebar and content in one spot, seperate
 * from the default styles.
 *
 * As an a heads up, we don't use `transform: translate3d()` here because when
 * mixed with `position: fixed;` for the sidebar toggle, it creates a new
 * containing block. Put simply, the fixed sidebar toggle behaves like
 * `position: absolute;` when transformed.
 *
 * Read more about it at http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2011/09/12/.
 */

.wrap,
.sidebar,
.sidebar-toggle {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
      -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.wrap,
.sidebar-toggle {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out;
          transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
}

.sidebar-toggle{
    z-index: 11;
}


#sidebar-checkbox:checked + .sidebar {
  z-index: 10;
  visibility: visible;
}
#sidebar-checkbox:checked ~ .sidebar,
#sidebar-checkbox:checked ~ .wrap,
#sidebar-checkbox:checked ~ .sidebar-toggle {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0rem);
      -ms-transform: translateX(0rem);
          transform: translateX(0rem);
}

#sidebar-checkbox:checked ~ .wrap {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(14rem);
      -ms-transform: translateX(14rem);
          transform: translateX(14rem);
}

/*
--------------------------------------------------
  Topbar nav
--------------------------------------------------
*/

/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Which contains similar code (with some small edits I made), but almost identical CSS. For some reason however, my React jsfiddle does not correctly display the font, or the smooth open/close css transform animation.

Is there something I need to do in order to make this work in a jsfiddle React? I want to have a shareable jsfiddle I can work on for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing css attributes when it comes to animation. `sidebar` class needs to be set on *left of -14rem* and *with of 14rem*, so this way its hidden, where as for toggle, it has to have 14 rem(so the transition is possible to move from -14 to 14rem)

as for font loading, I did not see any issue, its loading `font-family: "PT Serif", Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;`

```
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -14rem;
  width: 14rem;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  font-family: "PT Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: .875rem; /* 15px */
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.6);
  background-color: #202020;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
          transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

#sidebar-checkbox:checked ~ .sidebar,
#sidebar-checkbox:checked ~ .wrap,
#sidebar-checkbox:checked ~ .sidebar-toggle {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(14rem);
      -ms-transform: translateX(14rem);
          transform: translateX(14rem);
}
```